# Background job doesn't start

Tags: python, apscheduler

I am running three background with the following code, and I see only the third function being executed all the time.  The remaining two are never called.

Could you give some insights if I'm missing something here?

```py
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(job_defaults={'max_instances': 4})


def fun1():
    # I have some looping structure updating DB rows here


def fun2():
    # I have some looping structure updating DB rows here


def fun3():
    # I have some looping structure updating DB rows here


if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler.add_job(id='task1', func=fun1, trigger='interval', seconds=10)
    scheduler.add_job(id='task2', func=fun2, trigger='interval', seconds=10)
    scheduler.add_job(id='task3', func=fun3, trigger='interval', seconds=10)
```

Comment: I wanted to invoke these functions every 5-10 seconds. So i used this package.

Comment: Where you have started a scheduler [check this out](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/schedulers/background.html#apscheduler.schedulers.background.BackgroundScheduler)

Comment: import threading and in threading option use time duration and then function of which you want to output

Answer (score 0):

```
import threading


def fun1():
    print("HELLO")  # I have some looping structure updating DB rows here
    threading.Timer(5.0, fun2).start()  # I gave 5.0 to get print on 5 second


def fun2():
    print("HELLO CODER")  # I have some looping structure updating DB rows here
    threading.Timer(2.0, fun3).start()  # I gave 2.0 to get print on 2 second


def fun3():
    print("HELLO CODER ON THE WAY")
    threading.Timer(10.0, fun1).start()  # I gave 10.0 to get print on 10 second
    # I have some looping structure updating DB rows here


fun1()
```

Comment: Thanks @Ehsan Rahi for your response. you are calling only one fun1(), is that fine. Sorry for asking this question as am new to this threading etc. and do we need to apply this inside a class?

Comment: you can call function as per your priority for example you want to jump function from function 1 to function five then you give function5 name and after then if you jump from function5 to function11 directly you can . it depend on your choice. you can implement more to get more clearity. Thanks @George

Answer (score 0):

The reason nothing is happening is because you have not started the scheduler. Also, if you use `BackgroundScheduler` in that snippet, the process will exit immediately because there is nothing there that would prevent the main process from exiting. To prevent that, use `BlockingScheduler` instead.